# Choose random sequence of length 10 from (1,2) with equally many 1s and 2s. How many combinations are there?

Tags: combinations

Here is a small example. The aim is to draw a sequence of length N (even), which contains equally many 1s and 2s, and find the formula for the number of unique sequences. Here is the example for N=4:

1212,
2121,
1122,
2211,
2112,
1221

Six possibilities.

From a small numerical simulation, I also know there are 26 possibilities, if the length of the sequence is intended to be 10.

What is the exact mathematical logical formula for calculating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\{\text{your }2k\text{-tuples}\}\to \{S\subseteq\{1,\cdots,2k\}\,:\, \lvert S\rvert=k\}$ sending $x\mapsto\{i\in\{1,\cdots,2k\}\,:\, x_i=1\}$ is a bijection. Therefore the number of those $n$-tuples is $$H_n=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }n\text{ odd}\\ \binom{n}{n/2}&\text{if }n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$

It's unclear to me where your claim that $H_{10}=26$ instead of $252$ is supposed to come from.